# Egrep: How to search through a group of files for files that contain a specific date format?

Tags: unix, grep

Bit of a unix newby here.

I want to search through a list of files in a list of directories for every file that contains a cell with a date in it formatted a specific way. The \t are

egrep -l '\t0-90-9/0-90-9/0-90-90-90-9\t' */*

That's what I came up with, but nothing output when at least a few files should have. Really don't know grep let alone egrep so any assistance is very welcome!

Comment: Show some a short section of sample input and the corresponding desired output.

Answer (score 0):

What you're probably looking for is:

```
egrep -E -l '\t[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{4}\t' *
```

but without sample input/output it's just a guess.